# Material - UI and ReactJS working together

Tags: reactjs, webpack, material-ui

Working with ReactJS for the first time and I'm looking for some components I can use in my app. It appears that Material-UI will cover all the bases when it comes to components.

My question is if Material UI is compatible with newer versions of ReactJS

I've been experimenting with a project and I'm trying to include a table.
I've NPM installed material-ui but I am running into trouble when running the code

Here is the code

```
var React = require('react');
var Table = require('material-ui/lib/table/table');
var TableHeader = require('material-ui/lib/table/table-header');
var TableRow = require('material-ui/lib/table/table-row');
var TableHeaderColumn = require('material-ui/lib/table/table-header-column');
var TableBody = require('material-ui/lib/table/table-body');
var TableRowColumn = require('material-ui/lib/table/table-row-column');




var Home = React.createClass({

render: function() {
    return (
         <Table>
            <TableHeader>
              <TableRow>
                <TableHeaderColumn>ID</TableHeaderColumn>
                <TableHeaderColumn>Name</TableHeaderColumn>
                <TableHeaderColumn>Status</TableHeaderColumn>
              </TableRow>
            </TableHeader>
            <TableBody>
              <TableRow>
                <TableRowColumn>1</TableRowColumn>
                <TableRowColumn>John Smith</TableRowColumn>
                <TableRowColumn>Employed</TableRowColumn>
              </TableRow>
              <TableRow>
                <TableRowColumn>2</TableRowColumn>
                <TableRowColumn>Randal White</TableRowColumn>
                <TableRowColumn>Unemployed</TableRowColumn>
              </TableRow>
              <TableRow>
                <TableRowColumn>3</TableRowColumn>
                <TableRowColumn>Stephanie Sanders</TableRowColumn>
                <TableRowColumn>Employed</TableRowColumn>
              </TableRow>
              <TableRow>
                <TableRowColumn>4</TableRowColumn>
                <TableRowColumn>Steve Brown</TableRowColumn>
                <TableRowColumn>Employed</TableRowColumn>
              </TableRow>
            </TableBody>
          </Table>
    );
}

});

module.exports = Home;
```

I get 24 warnings like this when I run the code

"React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite components). Check the render method of `Home`"

and the Error

"Uncaught Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. Check the render method of `Home"

Any guidance would be appreciated.

**FIXED CODE**

```
var React = require('react');
var MUI = require('material-ui').default;
var Table = MUI.Table;
var TableHeader = MUI.TableHeader;
var TableRow = MUI.TableRow;
var TableHeaderColumn = MUI.TableHeaderColumn;
var TableBody = MUI.TableBody;
var TableRowColumn = MUI.TableRowColumn;




var Home = React.createClass({

render: function() {
    return (
         <Table>
            <TableHeader>
              <TableRow>
                <TableHeaderColumn>ID</TableHeaderColumn>
                <TableHeaderColumn>Name</TableHeaderColumn>
                <TableHeaderColumn>Status</TableHeaderColumn>
              </TableRow>
            </TableHeader>
            <TableBody>
              <TableRow>
                <TableRowColumn>1</TableRowColumn>
                <TableRowColumn>John Smith</TableRowColumn>
                <TableRowColumn>Employed</TableRowColumn>
              </TableRow>
              <TableRow>
                <TableRowColumn>2</TableRowColumn>
                <TableRowColumn>Randal White</TableRowColumn>
                <TableRowColumn>Unemployed</TableRowColumn>
              </TableRow>
              <TableRow>
                <TableRowColumn>3</TableRowColumn>
                <TableRowColumn>Stephanie Sanders</TableRowColumn>
                <TableRowColumn>Employed</TableRowColumn>
              </TableRow>
              <TableRow>
                <TableRowColumn>4</TableRowColumn>
                <TableRowColumn>Steve Brown</TableRowColumn>
                <TableRowColumn>Employed</TableRowColumn>
              </TableRow>
            </TableBody>
          </Table>
    );
}

});

module.exports = Home;
```

Comment: `Material-UI 0.14.1 introduced a regression that made it incompatible with CommonJS require().`

Comment: Can you elaborate slightly as this is how I have learned ReactJs, what do I have to do instead of require?

Comment: Seems you can use `require` since [bug](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#0142) was fixed in 0.14.2. And if you using 0.15.0-alpha2 there is [breaking changes](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#0150-alpha2). So, check your Material-UI version.

Comment: I'm using 0.15.0-alpha.2

Comment: Then add `.default` to all material-ui requires: `var Table = require('material-ui/lib/table/table').default;`

Comment: Great thanks! Fixed it. Appreciate the guidance